# GET HTTP/1.0についてとリクエストヘッドの必要性

Tags: http, https

HTTPについて学習を始めたところいきなりエラーが出てしまって解決法がよくわからないので質問させてください。

> $ telnet www.httpbin.org 80

とし
以下のようにGET /ip HTTP/1.0とすると

```
Connected to www.httpbin.org.herokudns.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /ip HTTP/1.0

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Cowboy
Date: Sun, 19 Aug 2018 09:27:06 GMT
Content-Length: 0

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

とBad Requestと出ます。302 Foundと出るはずなんですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか？

初歩的な質問になりますがよろしくお願いします

**質問追加**
リクエストヘッダに

> Host: www.httpbin.org

と追記すると良いようですが、なぜこれをする必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: リクエストヘッダに `Host: www.httpbin.org` を入力する必要があるのではないでしょうか。実際に試してみると、こちらの IP アドレスを返してきました(Status code: 200)。

Comment: ありがとうございます解決しました！しかしなぜリクエストヘッダにそれを追加する必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 「なぜリクエストヘッダに〜」の部分を質問欄に追記していただけますか(実は私もその必要性を知りたいと以前から思っていたのです)。

Comment: かしこまりました！タイトルも変更します！

Answer (score 1):

リクエストにヘッダが足りないのではないでしょうか。接続先がバーチャルホストのようですので、 Host: ヘッダを要求しているのだと思います。

```
$ telnet www.httpbin.org 80
Trying 52.44.174.39...
Connected to www.httpbin.org.herokudns.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /ip HTTP/1.1
Host: www.httpbin.org
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
Date: Sun, 19 Aug 2018 10:28:07 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 32
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Via: 1.1 vegur

{
  "origin": "125.30.32.159"
}
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: できました！しかしGET /ip HTTP/1.1とはどういうことでしょう？GETは1.0にしかないはずなのでは。。？

Comment: `HTTP/1.0`でも`Host`ヘッダ付与で`200`応答返ってきます。(ただし、応答は`HTTP/1.1`となりますが)

Comment: @JapaneseStudent さん、「GETは1.0にしかないはず」と言うのが誤っています。あなたのサイトはHostヘッダを正しく付与しないと動作しないように構成されているようです。ちなみにHostヘッダはHTTP/1.1で導入されたものなので、HostヘッダをつけるとHTTP/1.0とは言えないですね。Apacheなんかは(標準だと)HTTP/1.0を指定しても、HTTP/1.1と解釈して応答を返すようです。

Comment: @OOPer あなたのサイトとはhttpbinを指していますか？

Comment: あなたがアクセスしようとしているサイト`www.httpbin.org`のことです。